# Perform a Linq Many to Many Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

In SQL I have 2 tables.

---

**Sport**            **Athlete**
SportId          AthleteId
SportName    AthleteName

---

Their relation is many to many. So there is a third table that join them.

---

**AthleteSport**
AthleteId
SprortId

---

If i create an entity data model using the wizard the third table is disapeared and only creates the 2 main tables with the many to many relation.
how can I perform a query to find out what kind of sports athlete 'A' does? How to change them or add a new sport?

I want to use linq and c#.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Sport` entity, there will be a so called "navigation property" `Athletes` that contains all Athletes that belong to that `Sport` instance.
The same is true the other way around.

Comment: Ok! I was searching internet how to perform a join and I didn't notice that. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do `A.Sports` and get that list?

Comment: Yes I can... I'm so embarassed right now. I was look at the tree and missed the forest...